# How to add custom shading to a PDB file or viewer

Tags: molecules

I have a PDB file and viewing it through molstar, I have a numpy array of confidence intervals. Essentially an output from DeepMinds alphafold. Does anyone know how I can add a custom shade so that I can color the atoms/sub-structures according to their confidence interval?

I have not tried anything because I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since when janitors do bioinformatics? ;) This question might be better off on Bioinformatics.SE

Comment: Here is an example where they colored by structure quality, but I don't know where those values are uploaded: https://molstar.org/viewer/?snapshot-url=https%3A%2F%2Fmolstar.org%2Fdemos%2Fstates%2Fcytochromes.molx&snapshot-url-type=molx

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be to utilize the b-factor column in the pdb-file as suggested in the pymol wiki:
https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Color#Reassigning_B-Factors_and_Coloring

Comment: I can only use molstar, how do I accomplish this on molstar?